# liquibase diff shows missing constraints even on comparing a database to itself

Tags: liquibase

Somehow, liquibase always shows all my unique constraints as missing. My `liquibase.properties`:

```
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MY_DATABASE
username=user
password=pass
referenceUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MY_DATABASE
referenceUsername=user
referencePassword=pass
```

Note that the databases in the `url` and the `referenceUrl` parameter are the same. I run `liquibase diff` and what I get is:

```
Reference Database: postgres @ jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MY_DATABASE (Default Schema: public)
Comparison Database: postgres @ jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MY_DATABASE (Default Schema: public)

[...]

Missing Unique Constraint(s):
     email_type_lang_mandant_unique on emailentity(belongsto_userid, emailtype, language)
     filecard_delivery_source_unique on filecardentity(assignmentdelivery_id, original_cardid)
     lesson_delivery_source_unique on lessonentity(assignmentdelivery_id, sourcelesson_lessonid)
     link_type_lang_mandant_unique on linkentity(belongsto_userid, linktype, language)

     [...]

Liquibase 'diff' Successful
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I encountered the same issue, and I believe the reason is a bug in liquibase that only happens if your database name (a.k.a. catalog) contains upper-case letters.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the constraints, how are they defined? Just a guess, but it may be that they have different names. Doing a more detailed `diffChangelog` command may reveal what the issue is.

Comment: How can they have different names when their origin is the same database?

Comment: I didn't notice that you were comparing a database to itself. Yep, that seems very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. This happens if something (in this case the catalog (database name) contains upper case letters.

It appears that (by default) liquibase assumes that database identifiers are case insensitive. This is not correct for postgres (and others).

I found a related issues/pull request for that topic:
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/2888

If you were using liquibase as a java library the following should work for you:

```
comparisonDatabase.setObjectQuotingStrategy(ObjectQuotingStrategy.QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS);
```

Unfortunately I am not certain how to fix this in the standalone case.
However in the above pull request a new option `preserveSchemaCase` was added.
This sounds like it should work.